# Get values of input fields on page load in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to get values from html input fields on page load in asp.net? I want to load some data from database when page loads, but to do this I need to get value from input field. How should I do that?

I have html code

```
<input type="text" id="fromID" name="dateFrom" value="" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" runat="server" /> -
<input type="text" id="toID" name="dateTo" value="" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $today = moment();
    $("#toID").val($today.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    $("#fromID").val($today.subtract('days', 1).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
</script>
```

And on load I want to get these two dates because my query is limited with these two dates, but now code

```
toID.Value
```

returns empty string ("").
How should I get those two values from input?

Comment: Can you elaborate with some code exactly what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can use asp text boxes, which are rendered out as input elements like:

```
<asp:TextBox id="tb_one" runat="server" />
```

then your on load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var textone = tb_one.Text; //Get
       tb_one.Text = "Test"; //set
    }
```

However that being said, if this is on page load when you are getting information from the database, you should really look at why you need to get this data from a form that has not yet loaded. There will be a better way to store this data.